# Calculate areas from a sliced trapeze

Tags: geometry

I have an [area shown on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkv3u.png) for $n=5$. Total area always equals 1. I can slice the area to $n$ pieces, every piece have the same height which equals $\frac2n$, $x_0$ and $x_n$ are known variables where:
$$x_0, x_n \in <0;1>$$
$$x_n=1-x_0$$
I have to calculate the area of each piece.
$$P_i=\frac{x_i+x_{i+1}}n$$
$$P_0+P_1+...+P_{n-1}=\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{x_i+x_{i+1}}n=1$$
for $n=1$ there is only one area so: 
$$P_0=\frac{x_0+x_1}1=1$$
for $n=2$ there is one unknown $x_1$ that is always $\frac12$:
$$P_0=\frac{x_0+x_1}2$$
$$P_1=\frac{x_1+x_2}2$$
$$P_1+P_2=1$$
$$\frac{x_0+x_1+x_1+x_2}2=1$$
$$\frac{x_0+x_1+x_1+1-x_0}2=1$$
$$x_1=\frac12$$
I don't know how to calculate it further for $n>=3$. I modified equation to contain only $x$ parameters that are unknown:
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i\right)*2-n+1=0$$
for $n=3$:
$$(x_1+x_2)*2+1-3=0$$
$$2x_1+2x_2-2=0$$
At this point I am getting two and more unknown parameters. I believe it can be calculated. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is that the top of the trapezium is a line. Therefore it is quite easy to calculate the values of $x_k$ directly, without having to do it from the area formulas.

The line has slope $\frac {x_n - x_0} 2$ and the value $x_k$ occurs at a distance of $y = k\frac 2 n$ from the $x$-axis, so $$x_k = x_0 + \frac {x_n - x_0} 2 \left(k\frac 2 n\right) = x_0 + (x_n - x_0)\frac k n = \frac {(n-k)x_0 + k x_n} n$$
for all $k$.